# f# calc variance function

Tags: f#, finance

I am working through an F# function that calculates variance. I'm trying to step through each iteration to get the correct answer but think im getitng off track somewhere because I keep getting the wrong answer. Could someone please walk me through one iteration of this function to get me back on track

```
let variance values
    let average = Seq.average values
    let length = Seq.length values

    values
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> 1.0 / float length * (x - average) ** 2.0)
    |> Seq.sum
```

call is `variance [1.0..6.0]`

To me the first value passed is `1.0` so it would be `(1.0 / 6 * (1.0-3.5) ** 2.0)` and therefore `.166 * -2.5 ** 2.0`

I'm also unsure what the `**` means in formula I'm assuming multiply.
Correct answer should be `2.9166666667`

Comment: [`**`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353580.aspx) is the operator for `pow`.

Comment: thanks so could you show me how they get to 2.9166666667 there

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to understand, you can rewrite the code as follows:

```
let variance values = 
    let average = Seq.average values
    let length = Seq.length values

    let sum = values
               |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x - average) ** 2.0)
               |> Seq.sum in sum / float length

variance [1.0..6.0] |> printfn "%A"
```

Print: 2.916666667

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/09PHXn

By iteration:

```
let variancetest values = 
    let average = Seq.average values
    let length = Seq.length values
    values 
    |> Seq.iteri(fun i x ->
                 printfn "%i [%f]: %f ^ 2 = %A" i  x (x - average) ((x - average) ** 2.0))
    let sum = values
               |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x - average) ** 2.0)
               |> Seq.sum

    let flength = float length
    printfn "Sum = %f" sum
    printfn "1/length = %f" (1.0 / flength)
    printfn "Result / length = %f" (sum / flength)

variancetest [1.0..6.0]
```

Print:

```
0 [1.000000]: -2.500000 ^ 2 = 6.25
1 [2.000000]: -1.500000 ^ 2 = 2.25
2 [3.000000]: -0.500000 ^ 2 = 0.25
3 [4.000000]: 0.500000 ^ 2 = 0.25
4 [5.000000]: 1.500000 ^ 2 = 2.25
5 [6.000000]: 2.500000 ^ 2 = 6.25
Sum = 17.500000
1/length = 0.166667
Result / length = 2.916667
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/02r3qG

Comment: ahh thanks so much your the best let me ponder on that for a little ha